# The ViewData item that has the key 'Attribute' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm binding Categories and Genders in Dropdownlist. My Model has two attributes Mapped to the columns in other tables :

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose your category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Category Category_Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose your category")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Gender")]
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Gender Gender_Name { get; set; }
```

My ProductsController have a method called "Create" which is used for uploading

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(
                db.Categories.ToList(),
                "Category_ID",
                "Category_Name")
                ;
            ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(
                db.Genders.ToList(),
                "Gender_ID",
                "Gender_Name"
                );
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Products/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Products products)
        {
            if (products.Image.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "The Size of the
             Image is 2MB");
                return View();
            }
            if (!(products.Image.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || 
                products.Image.ContentType == "image/gif"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "File type allowed :
              jpeg and gif");
                return View();
            }

            byte[] data = new byte[products.Image.ContentLength];
            products.Image.InputStream.Read(data, 0, 
            products.Image.ContentLength);
            products.Product_Photo = data;
            db.Products.Add(products);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(products);
        }
```

The Corresponding View is :

```
@model  eKart.Models.Products

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype
              = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Products</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_Quantity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product_Quantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_Quantity)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product_Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_Price)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Product_Photo)
        </div>
         <div>

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Image, new{type="file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
           </div>

        <div class ="editor-label">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Category",
           (SelectList)ViewBag.Category,"Choose Category")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Category)
        </div>
        <div class ="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Gender)
        </div>
        <div class ="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Gender",(SelectList)ViewBag.Gender,"Choose 
           Gender")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Gender)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

When I Submit the form I hit the error at "Category" which is mentioned above.I checked StackOverFlow but didn't find useful information.I really wanna know what's going on and where I'm doing wrong.Thanks in advance your help

Comment: The error is self explanatory really the dropdownlist takes in a SelectListItem not selectlist, change your viewbag.category to be a selectlistitem

Comment: I'm a beginner for mvc.Could you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Try my answer, it is what he is talking about.

Comment: Because when you return the view in the POST method your do not reassign the `ViewBag` properties (as your did in the GET method) so they are `null` (hence the exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new property in your class:

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose your category")]
public string Category { get; set; }

public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Products();
    model.CategoryList = db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.CategoryName,
        Value = x.CategoryName
    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

EDIT: As StephenMuecke said in his comment you need to reassign the values to your `CategoryList` Property when `ModelState` is not valid.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Code here
    }

    product.CategoryList = db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.CategoryName,
        Value = x.CategoryName
    }).ToList();

    return View(product);
}
```

View:

```
<div class ="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, Model.CategoryList, "Choose category")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Category)
</div>
```

Do the same in 'Gender'

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue (although its good practice). Refer the duplicate to understand what the real issue is.

Comment: are the value and the text have same value which is CategoryName?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, but he said that he hits the error when he runs the project and not after submitting the form.

Comment: @sujaykodamala yes, it is because your `Category` property accepts string data type.

Comment: Sorry.It's not working.StephenMuecke was correct about this and I referred the duplicate post.It's the same issue.But thank you for your response @John Louie Cruz

Comment: I edited the answer :) and your welcome :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.I hit the error when I submit the form @John

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke is correct and i included the code when the modestate is not valid